# Failing test in react by using chart.js

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, chart.js

Hey guys I made a dashboard and used some charts with chart.js there and now After it is working fine my test are failing I can't figure out why please help

this is my dashboard

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './SuperAdminDashboard.module.css';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const line_state = {
  labels: [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Uptime',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [65, 59, 80],
    },
  ],
};

function SuperAdminDashboard(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.first_box}>
        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
            <h4>API Uptime Statistics</h4>
            <div>
              <Line
                type
                data={line_state}
                options={{
                  maintainAspectRatio: false,
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default SuperAdminDashboard;
```

and this is my testing file

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import SuperAdminDashboard from './SuperAdminDashboard';

describe('Testing the LoginPage', () => {
  test('should show the text on the website', () => {
    render(<SuperAdminDashboard />);
    expect(screen.getByText('Dashboard')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('API Uptime Statistics')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

and this is the problem I am getting

[image]